# How to update elements of D3 force layout when the underlying data changes

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm using one of the force layout examples (http://bl.ocks.org/1153292) to show a network on my web site.

I allow the user to choose which type of links to see at any given time. I notice that when I choose to see link type A, then add link type B and then remove link type A the remain links of type B are presented with A colors.

This is the code that runs to add the links to the svg diagram. I am changing the array `this.links` by adding and removing links from it. As you can see I set the class attribute but it is not updating - it remains of type of link A.

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(this.links)
   .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });
```

I currently work around this problem by updating the class attribute inside the tick function but this off course cause much un-needed work.

I read that the enter operation return a merged selection of the exist elements and also the new ones so the attr operation should update the exist one and set the new one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found the [answer in this post](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);

circle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5);

circle
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

circle.exit().remove();
```

The answer is that I need to call attr operator on the result of selectAll.data and not on the result of the append operator.

Comment: Ido, I know that this is an old post, but I believe I am experiencing the same problem that you were, and I still don't understand this solution.  Could you explain how it works--how it solves your original problem?  Thank you.

Comment: The solution works because the attr updates of cx and cy are outside of the enter() context, so they happen every time. In the original code, the attr functions are called within the enter() context, so they only get created once according to the object identity.  What did it for me was learning about key functions as the second argument to data(): http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/

Answer (score 4):

There is an example at http://bl.ocks.org/1095795 that shows adding and removing nodes from a force directed layout.  The links and nodes have to be handled separately and then the force layout has to be restarted.

```
function restart() {
  var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });

  link.enter().insert("svg:line", "g.node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  link.exit().remove();

  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://d3nwyuy0nl342s.cloudfront.net/images/icons/public.png")
      .attr("x", "-8px")
      .attr("y", "-8px")
      .attr("width", "16px")
      .attr("height", "16px");

  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "nodetext")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}
```

Comment: That's not enough. I'm adding and removing links and the problem is that it is no in-order. When I choose to see links of type A the link array is [A1,A2,A3] then I choose to see links of type B the array is [A1,A2,A3,B1,B2] then I choose to not see type A the array is [B1,B2]. D3 then choose to leave 2 elements and remove 3 but then I have to update the two elements because they are currently bound to A1 and A2 and I need them to be bound to B1 and B2.  I manage to do it by saving the vis.selectAll("g.Node").data(nodes) and update that.

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle that shows what you are currently doing and what the problem is then we may be able to help find a better solution.