# How to force recalculation of element attributes when data changes in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to work out how D3.js works, but I am having trouble understanding some (probably) basic principles... I would appreciate some help.

From what I understand, this snippet creates the `rect` SVG elements and sets their attributes:

```
var nodes = d3.selectAll('circle.node')
    .data(mydata)
  .enter()
    .append('rect').class('attr', 'node');

// now set some attributes on these SVG elements:
nodes.attr('...', function(d) {
    return '...'; 
});
```

When data changes later, my guess would be that I only need to do this:

```
d3.selectAll('circle.node')
    .data(mydata) // doesn't work as I would expect
```

However, the snippet above doesn't work as I would expect it to. If I want the attributes to change, I still need to call `attr()` on the selection, even though the attribute was specified as a function of the data and should be able to re-calculate itself. Even worse, I need to specify the identical anonymous function if I want to force this recalculation.

Why is that? Is there a `.updateMyAttributesFromData()` function that I have somehow missed? Something like this:

```
d3.selectAll('circle.node')
    .data(mydata)
    .updateMyAttributesFromData(); // not a real function
```

Am I missing something?

-

By the way, so as to avoid "duplicate question" marks: question [How to update elements when the underlying data changes with d3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992351/how-to-update-elements-when-the-underlying-data-changes-with-d3js) has a promising title, however the content is unfortunately completely different. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't miss anything, this is simply the way D3 works -- your attributes aren't updated automatically when you update the data. That is, you really do have to run the same code again when you assign new data. This is a design decision, not a bug.

You can however make it a bit easier (and less redundant) by wrapping the code that does all this in a function that takes e.g. the data.

```
function update(data) {
  var sel = d3.selectAll("foo").data(data);

  sel.enter().append("foo");

  // elements added in the enter selection merge into the update selection,
  // so this attribute is set for the elements that have just been added as well
  sel.attr("foo", "bar");

  sel.exit().remove();
}
```

One reason for not doing the attribute updating automatically (apart from the added complexity of the implementation) is that rendering elements is usually the bottleneck in data-intensive applications. If this happened automatically, you would always incur this performance overhead even if you didn't actually need to update anything. In addition, it wouldn't play nice with the `.exit()` selection (i.e. update the attributes of elements which are going to be removed anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, is there a way to manually trigger attribute recalculation (without specifying the attribute values in `attr()`)? My main concern here is code maintainability (DRY).

Comment: No. Again, if you're worried about redundancy, make a function to set all the attributes and then do `sel.call(attributeFunction)`.