# d3js: How to remove nodes on exit properly?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm having a problem updating nodes in my force layout. I have used some help from another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070899/d3-js-how-to-remove-nodes-when-link-data-updates-in-a-force-layout) for updating nodes. This worked out fine until I realized that everything(circle svg, lines, text, etc) were under their own "g" tag.

So that means that I cannot manipulate any of the text like I did before.   If you compare [this](http://jsfiddle.net/clanofnoobs/njyojesa/)   with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/clanofnoobs/tnrctL8s/) you can see that in the first fiddle, I can't increase the text size based on the click. `d3.select(this).select("text")` does not work since the "g" tags do not include a circle and a text together.

So I need to be able to manipulate the text in correspondence to the node. The second fiddle handles that but it has a problem updating the nodes. If you hit the update button, it updates all the nodes but it does not remove existing nodes. For the first fiddle, update works fine but i can't manipulate the text like I mentioned earlier. So for a solution, I need to either find a way to manipulate the text in the first fiddle, or for the second fiddle, I need to somehow have it properly update all the nodes on exit(). I would say the second fiddle would be more natural to work with since the nodes are set out in a structured layout. i.e, each circle and it's corresponding text are in "g" tags just like what you would group in divs.

Comment: It would help to include the links to the fiddles here in your post, to make it more clear which fiddles in the other post you're referencing.

Comment: There are links. They're just hyperlinks. I wasn't able to put the direct links to the fiddles for some reason. Second sentence in the second para.