# How to refresh "index" in eventFunction(d,index) for force.links() after splice?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I ran into a problem and I do not understand what's going on. Sorry if this is obvious.

My code which works fine:

```
var path = mainGroup
        .append("svg:g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(json.links, function(d) {
            return d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")            
        .on("dblclick", function(d, i) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {

                json.links.forEach(function(obj, index){
                    if (obj.source.index == d.source.index && obj.target.index == d.target.index) {
                         json.links.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                })

            path.data(force.links(), function(d) {
                return d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index;
            }).exit().remove();
        }
    });
```

But I don't want in `dblclick` the code `json.links.forEach(..` and replace to:
http://jsfiddle.net/lastjeka/szpco5gj/

```
.on("dblclick", function(d, i) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {

            json.links.splice(i, 1);              

            path.data(force.links(), function(d) {
                return d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index;
            }).exit().remove();
        }
```

`json.links.splice(i, 1);` works only for first `dblclick`. Next dblclick may or may not remove element from `json.links`, 
because `i` didn't update relatively new `force.links()` when the first call `dblclick`.

Is a bug or my misunderstanding? Thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992351/how-to-update-elements-of-d3-force-layout-when-the-underlying-data-changes) may help.

Comment: Here is another question. The problem is not the creation of new elements on the graph, but the fact that `i` for event `function(d, i)` doesn't update after `d.splice`.

Comment: Yes, you're changing the data, but not the elements (which determine the index `i`). After changing the underlying data, you need to update the DOM elements and reattach the handlers.

Comment: I add  refreshGraph();. And `i` doesn't update after it. See https://rbac-githubjeka.c9.io/index.html . If I use `json.links.forEach` without `refreshGraph()` then all works fine.

Comment: That's what I'm saying -- after changing the data and shown elements, you need to reattach the event handlers.

Comment: How? :) Specifically for my code, please if you can (https://ide.c9.io/githubjeka/rbac)

Comment: You call the `.on("dblclick", ...)` code on the updated selection.

Comment: And? What do you mean? Is it bad?

Comment: Well are you doing that? I can't access your code, it seems to require an account.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lastjeka/szpco5gj/ (problem in 85 row) Thanks.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work at all for me. I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Omg. So sorry ^_^ http://jsfiddle.net/lastjeka/szpco5gj/1/

Comment: Thanks. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/szpco5gj/2/) is what I mean. After updating the links, set the handler again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would probably have chosen the best answer it. And you can somehow avoid the call sel.on ("dblclick", dblclick); inside dblclick()? It's not pretty.

Comment: That's the very thing that makes it work! What do you mean that it's not pretty? If this answers your question, I'll add it as a proper answer.

Comment: Bind an event handler in the handler. IMHO code is smell. But I understand the problem, thank you. you can add answer. I will check it.

Comment: I'll add the answer. I understand your concern about the code structure, but this really is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-add the event handler inside the event handler. That is, after removing the elements, you need to rerun the code to set everything up properly:

```
function dblclick(d, i) {
                // remove links
                var sel = path.data(force.links(), function(d) {
                    return d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index;
                });
                sel.on("dblclick", dblclick);
                sel.exit().remove();
            }
    }
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/szpco5gj/2/).